# hibernet one to many on web

Tags: java, hibernate

I am completely new in Hibernate ORM world, recently reading mapping specially one-to-many relation. But i am facing some problem to understand.

I am using this link to understand hibernate relation.
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

please have a look the code.

```
public class Student {

  private long studentId;

 private String studentName;

 private Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers


//setter getter
}

public class Phone {

    private long phoneId;
    private String phoneType;
    private String phoneNumber;

//setter getter

}
```

i understand it.

confusion is here.

```
Set<Phone> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>(); 

phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("house","32354353"));

phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("mobile","9889343423")); 

Student student = new Student("Eswar", phoneNumbers); 

session.save(student);
```

1. Does this only one code session.save(student), store value in both table ? if no then  why we didn't  write code to save phoneNumbers like session.save(phoneNumbers).
2. Once this above code is executed then the value will be stored in both table or object(STUDENT and PHONE) right ?. I think each time we execute this code, this code insert value in both table. i don't like it. i want value should be store on only second table(PHONE).

So how will i store value in only PHONE object ?
or how will we implement this relation where user will select STUDENT through combobox and fill value in PHONE object through simple textboxes. then finally save it.like product/category.

3.please help or suggest some good tutorial where hibernate is implemented (specially one-to-many and many to many relation) in web application. i have seen many tutorial but all these are implemented through main method.

sorry for the poor English
thanks.

Comment: I don't see your annotations, phone numbers should be annotated with @OneToMany

Comment: Could you add the code where you create your session?

Comment: https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it should save both student and phone number in their own table. If you annotate the right way. Student should be something like this:

   ```
   @Entity
       @Table(name = "student")

       public class Student {
       @id

       @GeneratedValue
       private long studentId;

       @column(name = "studentName")
       private String studentName;

       @OneToMany
       private Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers

       //setter getter
   }

   public class Phone {

   private long phoneId;
   private String phoneType;
   private String phoneNumber;

   //setter getter

   }
   ```

   Then there is also some configuration to do. I'd advice you to read this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/index.htm
2. In the case of your code it doesn't much. But if you configure hibernate the right way you can decide in which table/column a value should be saved
3. [Hibernate tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/index.htm) - [Tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com)

Comment: you have said "I don't see your annotations, phone numbers should be annotated with @OneToMany" actually i didn't wanted to stretch question too long. so i have written only main logic. i have already given a link for complete code.
ok. Casper many many thanks for your reply. but still confused sorry.